# How can I find out the base address of a debuggee process in Visual Studio C++ debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, executable, base-address

Say, I just loaded my executable in the Visual Studio C++ debugger and triggered a breakpoint. I have a "fault offset" where the app crashed, that I'm assuming I need to add to the base address where the app loaded up at to get the spot where it crashed.

So how do I get that base address from the VS IDE debugger?

PS. The app was not compiled or changed in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the `Modules` window from the `Debug | Windows | Modules` menu.  This shows a list of all the modules (the EXE and the DLLs) and includes their load addresses.